# automatically failing custom request in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-request

I have created a custom request that needs to check a variable before proceeding forward. This is my CustomRequest and have something like this

```
class CustomRequest extends FormRequest
{

    public function rules(){
        if ($variable == "abc") {
            return [
                "method"             => [
                    "required",
                    "in:mail",
                ]
            ];
        }
    }

}
```

And in my controller it is

```
public function addMethod(CustomRequest $request)
{
    //
}
```

I want that if the `$variable` is not equal to `abc` it just automatically fails and redirects the user back with message. I don't know how to do that.

Is there any possibility to achieve such functionality?

Comment: This is akin to CSRF checks, so it's possible. You just need to check for `Input::get('variable')` or `$request->get('variable')`

Comment: I reckon, but I just don't want to touch the controller method. Everything should be in Request class

Comment: Using a [Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware) might be the best use for this instead of the CustomRequest class. Middlewares process the request first before it gets to a controller.

Comment: maybe try `if($variable != "abc"){return back()->withMessage('message')}` im not sure if this is what you mean tho

Comment: Did you authorize the request ?

Comment: @SagarGautam I think authorize is the right answer. I should be able to redirect?

Comment: @anyber Middleware means updating routes or Controller which I cannot.

Comment: @HashtagForgotName yep something like that

Comment: @Ali Rasheed then you can make the message like this `['fail' => 'error message']`

Answer (score 1):

Add following function in your custom form request class.

```
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}
```

Then it will work.

By default, it is set to false and we have to set it true manually.

Comment: Is there a way to add a message and redirect?

Comment: @AliRasheed You have to make a custom rule for that which will handle all these things

Comment: If it fails authorization is throws an exception, is it possible to rather send a json response? Keeping in mind no changes in controller method.

Comment: @AliRasheed You can send validation errors as json response by extending a function of the form request. That is failedValidation

Answer (score 1):

Just make a middleware, put it in the Kernel so that it can be applied for all routes and inside the middleware, you can check the variable value and take appropriate action.

Comment: Hmm, this sounds interesting too. But I should be able to skip some routes after in web.php or controller?

Comment: In that case you dont put it in kernet as global ones, just register it normally and then in your web.php, you can create a route group where you can apply this middleware to selected routes